# I am trying to find specific links on users desktops and create a file logging the results

Tags: vbscript

I have used similar before and I have local admin rights on every computer in our network.  The following code generates an error on line 16 char 1.

line 16   For Each objsubfolder In objFSO.GetFolder("\" & strComputer & "%HOMEPATH%").subfolders

If the file exists it should write a line in the text file to indicate so for each user with a profile.  If the file doesn't exist is should write a line in the same text file.

The error I get is Path not found 800A004C.

The computers.txt file contains a list of all the computers I want to check.

```
InputFile = "computers.txt"
Const DeleteReadOnly = True
Const ForAppending = 8

Dim goFS  : Set goFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim gsLog : gsLog     = ".\logdemo.log"
WScript.Echo gsLog, "exists:", CStr(goFS.FileExists(gsLog))
'                           .OpenTextFile(filename[, iomode[, create[, format]]])
Dim goLog : Set goLog = goFS.OpenTextFile(gsLog, ForAppending, True)
goLog.WriteLine Now & " start"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile)
Do While Not (objFile.AtEndOfStream)
strComputer = objFile.ReadLine
For Each objsubfolder In objFSO.GetFolder("\\" & strComputer & "%HOMEPATH%").subfolders

If objFSO.FileExists(objsubfolder.Path & "\desktop\program1.LNK") Then
golog.WriteLine Join(Array(Now, strComputer, objsubfolder, "This Computer has Program 1"))

Else

golog.WriteLine Join(Array(Now, strComputer, objsubfolder, "None"))

End If
Next
Loop

golog.WriteLine Now & " End"
golog.WriteLine "-----------------------------------------------------------"
golog.Close

MsgBox "Done"
```

Answer (score 1):

To prove that the FSO does not expand environment strings automagically:

```
  Dim oFS : Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim oWS : Set oWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Dim sPath

  sPath = "%windir%\addins"
  WScript.Echo qq(sPath), CStr(oFS.FolderExists(sPath))
  sPath = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%\addins")
  WScript.Echo qq(sPath), CStr(oFS.FolderExists(sPath))
```

output:

```
"%windir%\addins" False
"C:\WINDOWS\addins" True
```

So put some work into feeding a valid path to .GetFolder().